# Forming triangles from random breaks

Tags: python, math

Take the following question: You have a segment [0,1]. You choose two points on this segment at random. The points divide the segment into three smaller segments. What is the probability that the segments form a triangle?

Does anyone know how to design a discrete program for this which would simulate this problem with the integers 1 to 100 and be able to tell if a triangle could be formed or not?

Thanks, if not, sorry to waste your time.

Comment: This is a very poorly written question (and nor is there any evidence of an attempt at a solution).   Re: the triangle, do you mean that the three segments _could_ form a triangle if the points 0 and 1 were folded so that they meet?   In ¶2, what do the numbers 1 to 100 have to do with the problem?

Comment: How would the integers 1 to 100 be used? Do you want 100 possible break points in the segment [0, 1] and those to be chosen with uniform random distribution? Are the endpoints possibly chosen? This could be done easily choosing all representable points in that interval. How many times to do want to repeat this: just once? How are the results to be returned or displayed? You need to clarify your problem. Also, what have you tried, and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, I want 100 possible break points and for these to be chosen randomly and independently. I want the probability that a triangle can be formed. I made no attempt because I have no idea how to program in Python.

Comment: By be able to form a triangle I mean have the largest piece be less than $0.5$ in length.

Comment: @JohnSmith you never even mention python before...

Comment: Are both points chosen from the entire interval, so the first point chosen does not affect the second point? (There are other random ways to choose the points.)

Comment: Yes, both points are chosen randomly and independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for *sampling*, and it seems that you don't want discrete but continuous one.

C# code:

```
private static Random s_Random = new Random();

private static bool TestForTriangle() {
  double x1 = s_Random.NextDouble();
  double x2 = s_Random.NextDouble();

  double a, b, c;

  if (x1 < x2) {
    a = x1;
    b = x2 - x1;
    c = 1.0 - x2;
  }
  else {
    a = x2;
    b = x1 - x2;
    c = 1.0 - x1;
  }

  return (a < b + c) && (b < a + c) && (c < a + b);
}
```

...

```
int n = 1000000;

double success = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  if (TestForTriangle())
    success += 1.0;

double probability = success / n;

Console.Write(probability);
```

Outcome (may vary):

```
0.250204
```

As you can see, we have a good estimation of `1/4 == 0.25`.

**Edit**: *integer* sampling (random x1, x2 within `[1..100]`) is *biased*:

```
private static bool TestForTriangle() {
  // 1 - left iclusive; 101 - exclusive: so we have [1..100] range
  int x1 = s_Random.Next(1, 101);
  int x2 = s_Random.Next(1, 101);

  int a, b, c;

  if (x1 < x2) {
    a = x1;
    b = x2 - x1;
    c = 100 - x2;
  }
  else {
    a = x2;
    b = x1 - x2;
    c = 100 - x1;
  }

  return (a > 0) && (b > 0) && (c > 0) && // you may want to comment this out
         (a < b + c) && (b < a + c) && (c < a + b);
}
```

Typical outcome is something like

```
0.235566
```

Comment: Wait so is the program using only the integers between 1 and 100 and nothing in between? If so, how could I change the range of values it can have.

Comment: @John Smith: no I don't use any *integers* in between `[1..100]` but a continuous range `[0..1)`: "You have a **segment [0,1]**. You choose two points on this segment "

Comment: Is there a way to change this, because this is crucial to the problem. Thanks anyway though!

Comment: Re: your edit, AFAICS the OP's completely confused about the role that the numbers 1..100 are supposed to play in this problem.

Comment: @John Smith: if you insist on *integer sampling*, you'll get the *biased* estimation (underestimated) probabiity.

Comment: Thanks this is just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in node.js (I'm not doing your Python homework for you) that generates one million random triples, and counts how many of those could form a legal triangle if the three segments were folded together.

```
let count = 0;
let samples = 1e6;

for (let i = 0; i < samples; ++i) {
    let x1 = Math.random();
    let x2 = Math.random();

    let a = Math.min(x1, x2);       // first segment
    let b = Math.max(x1, x2) - a;   // second segment
    let c = 1 - (a + b);            // third segment

    let valid = (a + b) > c && (a + c) > b && (b + c) >a;

    if (valid) ++count;
}

console.log(count / samples);
```

Comment: This does not work for me because as stated in the comments, you need a program which will find the probability that the largest piece is less than 0.5 (and hence forms a triangle) and one which allows DISCRETE values like the integers between 1 and 100. Thanks anyway however!

Comment: I solved this for my own mathematical edification, not yours.    The `valid` test in my code is _the_ canonical test for a legal triangle, without making the assumption that `a + b + c == 1`.